# How can the docker container communicate host machine?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, macvlan

Host machine ip:192.168.123.2  Gateway:192.168.123.1

Adapter is enp3s0, so I create a docker network in host:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet 192.168.123.0/24 --gateway 192.168.123.1 -o parent=enp3s0 -o macvlan_mode=bridge macnet
```

Run a container set IP

```
docker run --net macnet --ip 192.168.123.102 --name hd3  -it  ubuntu bash
```

Container and Host machine ping Gateway 192.168.123.1 are all work.
But doesn't work between the container and the host.

Container:
ping Gateway is  OK
ping Host isn't OK

Host:
ping Gateway is OK
ping Container isn't OK

Why and How can I communicate between the docker container and host machine?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent enough docker (18.03 and more), see, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541681/6309), if you can use:

```
host.docker.internal
```

That was first [documented for MacOS as host](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible), but should work on Windows host too.